# Codeigniter project URL is showing 404 exeception page in chrome browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I have a project URL which was working fine from all browsers, but recently it is showing 404 page when trying from chrome but loading properly in firefox. Do you have any idea? Note: I checked the folder permissions.

Comment: Have you checked your web server logs?

Comment: No. Can you tell where is the log file?

Comment: are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: Using Linux - ununtu

Comment: try looking in ```/var/logs/apache2/error.log```

Comment: It is showing [Tue Apr 28 15:56:11 2015] [error] [client 10.10.2.151] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico but my project folder is in /var/www/project/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76446/discussion-between-sanjay-kumar-n-s-and-justin-erswell).